# URLComponents adds cryptic characters when adding path

Tags: swift, url

I have a problem when adding a path to an URLComponents object. Please have a look at following code:

```
func urlWith(path: String, andParameters parameters: [String:String]) -> URL? {
        let urlString = "https://some.nice.url/path/to"

        guard var urlComponents = URLComponents(string: urlString) else {
            return nil
        }

        let optionalURLQueryItems = parameters.map {
            return URLQueryItem(name: $0, value: $1)
        }
        let queryItems = optionalURLQueryItems

        urlComponents.path += path

        urlComponents.queryItems = queryItems

        return urlComponents.url
    }
```

When I pass a (valid) String to this method for a path, for example `"/somewhere"`, the url looks like this:

```
https://some.nice.url/path/to%E2%80%8B/somewhere
```

The weird thing is, when I change the appending path method to this:

```
urlComponents.path += "/somewhere"
```

The URL looks like this:

```
https://some.nice.url/path/to/somewhere
```

So the question is, why is URLComponents adding `%E2%80%8B` to the URL and how to solve this issue?

Any help is much appreciated!

**UPDATE**
After checking the answers and the comments, I copied over the whole method to blank playground. There it works as expected. I have no idea why it does not work in Xcode. Then I just restarted Xcode and guess what, it worked. So I took the advice with the paths as suggested and here we go. But the remaining question is: When I type everything letter by letter (url and path), why does it work in playground but not in Xcode? Why does a restart solve the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend to create the URL from the base URL and concatenate the path

```
func urlWith(path: String, andParameters parameters: [String:String]) -> URL? {
    let urlString = "https://some.nice.url"

    guard var urlComponents = URLComponents(string: urlString) else {
        return nil
    }
    let optionalURLQueryItems = parameters.map {
        return URLQueryItem(name: $0, value: $1)
    }
    let queryItems = optionalURLQueryItems
    urlComponents.path = "/path/to/" + (path.hasPrefix("/") ? String(path.dropFirst()) : path)
    urlComponents.queryItems = queryItems
    return urlComponents.url
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately it's the same behavior.

Comment: The example in the question does not behave that way. `%E2%80%8B` aka `0x8203` is a *zero width space* character.

Comment: I copied over the whole method and tried, this is the output: (lldb) po urlComponents.url
▿ Optional<URL>
  ▿ some : https://some.nice.url/path/to/%E2%80%8B/somewhere
    - _url : https://some.nice.url/path/to/%E2%80%8B/somewhere

Comment: According to the output it's the last character of the `path` parameter or the first character of `"/somewhere"`. This character is invisible (which *zero space* implies). Don't copy the stuff. Retype it.

Comment: I retyped it letter for letter. No change in Xcode. But as stated in another comment to the other answer, it works in playground, not in Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

You have a [left-to-right mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left-to-right_mark) at the start of your `path` parameter. It's either because it's being localized, or because you've copy-and-pasted it from somewhere that includes it.

Comment: After researching I thought the same. But even when I type it letter for letter, it's the same response.

Comment: Generate a MVCE that demonstrates this (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I am certain you have a left-to-right mark here that you're not seeing, and creating the MVCE will discover that.

Comment: So I copied over the whole method to a blank playground. There it works as expected. So why does it not work in Xcode? Even when I create a new class, add the method and print out the result, it behaves the same.

Comment: A playground is still Xcode. What you mean is it doesn't work in this project. Something in your project is different than the playground. Keep removing things until you find what that is. Create a new project; move over the minimum files you need to make this compile and see if it reproduces. Binary search until you find what's different. Something is different in your code.

Comment: Thanks Rob, I still don't know why this happened. After restarting Xcode it worked without a change.